# ICU4J - the same currency symbol either as a prefix or suffix depending on locale

Tags: java, icu, icu4j

I want to place correctly the $ symbol, either as a prefix or suffix, depending on locale using the `MessageFormat` class, but without success so far. I need to localize the currency symbol *placement*, but not the symbol itself.

In my message I use:

> The car cost is {0, number, currency}

and I create an instance of MessageFormat calling:

```
MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat(msg, locale);
```

The result is that currency symbol is placed correctly but it has been also changed depending on used locale. For locale en_us I get $, for locale pl_pl I get zł.

So the question is, how to tell *MessageFormat* to use always the same currency symbol ($ in my case) but putting it (as the prefix or suffix) depending on locale?

Based on [MessageFormat manual](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/MessageFormat.html) looks like that *{0, number, currency}* is formatted using *NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(getLocale())*, so I wonder if it is possible at all.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it is possible. 
The *CurrencyAmount* object, set up as the USD currency, should be passed as an argument to the *format* method of *MessageFormat* class.